# Сохранить котировки с yahoo finance (Pandas.Panel) для нескольких фирм в разные CSV файлы

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, анализ-данных

Не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы из файла txt, в котором на каждом новой строчке стоит тикет акции, построчно скачивались котировки.

Вот основной код:

```
from pandas_datareader import data

input = open('C:/Users/II/Downloads/1.txt', 'r')
s = input.read()

r = data.DataReader(s, 'yahoo', '1900-01-01')
r.to_csv('C:/Users/II/Downloads/'+s+'_data.csv')
```

Не могу понять как ставить while или for line, прошу написать в примере кода. Спасибо.

Пример того, что получается на выходе csv файла.

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2010-11-18,35.0,35.990002000000004,33.889998999999996,34.189999,457044300,30.210939
2010-11-19,34.150002,34.5,33.110001000000004,34.259997999999996,107842000,30.272792
2010-11-22,34.200001,34.48,33.810001,34.080002,36650600,30.113744
2010-11-23,33.950001,33.990002000000004,33.189999,33.25,31170200,29.380338000000002
2010-11-24,33.73,33.799999,33.220001,33.48,26138000,29.58357
2010-11-26,33.41,33.810001,33.209998999999996,33.799999,12301200,29.866328000000003
2010-11-29,33.799999,33.810001,33.07,33.799999,27776900,29.866328000000003
```

Comment: Приведите пример ожидаемого CSV фала (5-7 строк). Вы хотите сохранить котировки для разных фирм в разные файлы?

Comment: У вас заголовок несоответствует вопросу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE: 2020-06-08**

Код из `old answer` (внизу) который работал для достаточно старых версий `pandas` и `pandas-datareader` и который не работает сейчас, потому, что в старых версиях указанных библиотек использовался тип данных `pandas.Panel`, преднанзначенный для хранения 3D данных. В более поздних версиях Pandas разработчики решили отказаться от его поддержки и в современных версиях Pandas этого типа данных нет. Соответственно разработчики `pandas-datareader` вынуждены были изменить свою библиотеку, чтобы не использовать более не поддерживаемый тип данных. Теперь вместо использования устаревшего 3D Panel, в `pandas-datareader` используют `pandas.DataFrame` с `multi-level columns`.

Для современных версий `pandas` и `pandas-datareader` можно сделать так:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as wb

p = wb.DataReader(stocklist, 'yahoo', '2019-01-01').swaplevel(axis=1)
for name in p.columns.get_level_values(0).unique():
    p[name].to_csv(fr"c:/temp/data_{name}.csv")
```

---

**Old answer:**

Вот пример для версий библиотек `pandas` и `pandas-datareader` начала 2017-го года:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as wb

tickers_fn = r'D:\temp\tickers.txt'
with open(tickers_fn) as f:
    stocklist = f.read().splitlines()

p = wb.DataReader(stocklist, 'yahoo', '1900-01-01')

# show Panel axes...
#print(p.axes)

for ticker in p.minor_axis:
    p.loc[:, :, ticker].dropna().to_csv('d:/temp/{}_data.csv'.format(ticker))
```

tickers.txt:

```
AAPL
GOOG
FB
AMZN
```

Что получилось (я приведу только несколько первых строк для нескольких файлов):

GOOG_data.csv:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2004-08-19,100.000168,104.060182,95.960165,100.340176,44871300.0,50.119968
2004-08-20,101.010175,109.08018700000001,100.500174,108.31018300000001,22942800.0,54.10099
2004-08-23,110.75019099999999,113.480193,109.050183,109.40018500000001,18342800.0,54.645447
```

FB_data.csv:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2012-05-18,42.049999,45.0,38.0,38.23,573576400.0,38.23
2012-05-21,36.529999,36.66,33.0,34.029999,168192700.0,34.029999
2012-05-22,32.610001000000004,33.59,30.940001000000002,31.0,101786600.0,31.0
```

AMZN_data.csv:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
1997-05-15,29.25,30.0,23.125,23.5,72156000.0,1.958333
1997-05-16,23.625,23.75,20.5,20.75,14700000.0,1.729167
1997-05-19,21.125,21.25,19.5,20.5,6106800.0,1.708333
```

AAPL_data.csv:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
1980-12-12,28.75,28.875,28.75,28.75,117258400.0,0.425
1980-12-15,27.375001,27.375001,27.25,27.25,43971200.0,0.402826
1980-12-16,25.375,25.375,25.25,25.25,26432000.0,0.373261
```

Я бы вам посоветовал (если есть такая возможность) не хранить данные в CSV формате. Он не поддерживает сохранение типов данных и к тому же он очень медленный. Попробуйте воспользоваться [HDF5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37012035/5741205) или [Feather-Format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42022053/5741205).

PS посмотрите также на [этот ответ (похожий)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37763947/5741205)

Comment: Человечище! Спасибо, то, что нужно.

Comment: @Alex, всегда рад помочь :-)

Comment: А почему HDF5 предпочтительнее, чем например JSON?

Comment: @Alex, по тем же причинам - отсутствие информации о типах данных (например для работы с датами и временем нужна конверсия) и  скорость