# Ошибка при попытке скачать несколько данных

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, анализ-данных

При попытке скачать котировки акций из списка txt, возникает ошибка:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'minor_axis'

Как исправить правильно?

Файл к которому обращение происходит - просто .txt с записью:

```
GM
F
AAPL
```

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as wb

tickers_fn = r'C:/Python/1.txt'
with open(tickers_fn) as f:
    stocklist = f.read().splitlines()

p = wb.DataReader(stocklist, 'yahoo', '2019-01-01')

# show Panel axes...
#print(p.axes)

for ticker in p.minor_axis:
    p.loc[:, :, ticker].dropna().to_csv('C:/Python/{}_data.csv'.format(ticker))
```

Comment: Только вчера видел этот же вопрос. У DataFrame нет аттрибута minor_axis, его даже у Panel нет, там есть minor_xs. Откуда этот пример все берут?

Comment: в доках есть minor_axis но описание пустое, будто задел на будущее. для чего оно в коде ? может заменить ?

Comment: @CrazyElf, [в старых версиях Pandas существовал тип Panel для 3D данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/627136)  и старые версии `pandas-datareader` использовали Panel. В современных версиях `Panel` убрали, поэтому старые примеры больше не работают)

Comment: @MaxU Ну вот я смутно помню что-то такое. Не пойму только откуда разные посты вдруг с одним и тем же примером появляются )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно вы воспользовались [кодом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/627156/211923), который работал для достаточно старых версий `pandas` и `pandas-datareader` и который не работает сейчас, потому, что в старых версиях указанных библиотек использовался тип данных `pandas.Panel`, преднанзначенный для хранения 3D данных. В более поздних версиях Pandas разработчики решили отказаться от его поддержки и в современных версиях Pandas этого типа данных нет. Соответственно разработчики `pandas-datareader` вынуждены были изменить свою библиотеку, чтобы не использовать более не поддерживаемый тип данных. Теперь вместо использования устаревшего 3D Panel, в `pandas-datareader` используют `pandas.DataFrame` с `multi-level columns`.

Для современных версий `pandas` и `pandas-datareader` можно сделать так:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as wb

p = wb.DataReader(stocklist, 'yahoo', '2019-01-01').swaplevel(axis=1)
for name in p.columns.get_level_values(0).unique():
    p[name].to_csv(fr"c:/temp/data_{name}.csv")
```